# How to make such a sidebar on a 3d scene so that it does not hide the scene?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, javafx-8, javafx-3d

How to make such a settings panel so that you can see the scene with 3d figures as in the picture?
my scene is under the panel.
I create a BorderPane,
And she completely closes the scene.
[image]

[image]

My code is in the second picture, but I don’t know how to make the scene visible

```
 RadioButton rdoEasy = new RadioButton("Easy");
    RadioButton rdoMedium = new RadioButton("Medium");
    RadioButton rdoHard = new RadioButton("Hard");
    var groupDifficulty = new ToggleGroup();
    groupDifficulty.getToggles().addAll(
            rdoEasy,
            rdoMedium,
            rdoHard
    );
    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
    toolBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    toolBar.getItems().addAll(
            new Separator(),
            rdoEasy,
            rdoMedium,
            rdoHard,
            new Separator()
    );
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setLeft(toolBar);
    borderPane.setCenter(group);
    borderPane.getCenter();
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, orgSceneX, orgSceneY,true,SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `SubScene` for the 3D content?

Comment: I tried with SubScene
It works thanks!